# Code to search text file for exact string and performing action if found is failing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

So, I wrote some code that is suppose to read a text file and then check for an instance of a specific string. If that string exists it will need to perform an action. I have added some message boxes to let me know the progress of the function. The problem is, it is not finding the word. Here is my code:

```
private void test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("C:\\testing\\mslogon.log");
    string sLine = "";
    ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
    MessageBox.Show("File Read");

    while (sLine != null)
    {
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
        if (sLine != null)
        {
            arrText.Add(sLine);
        }
    }

    if (arrText.Contains("Invalid"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Word Invalid Found");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nada");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you are checking arrText for an element that is exactly equal to "Invalid".  If "Invalid" is embedded in some larger string, it will not find it.

To check whether any of the strings contain Invalid, you'd have to do:

```
foreach(var line in arrText)
{
    if (line.Contains("Invalid")) { MessageBox.Show("Word 'Invalid' Found"); break; }
}
```

Using File.ReadAllText as @Alexei mentions would enable you to do something you are wanting to do and would look something like this:

```
String wholeFile = File.ReadAllText();
if (wholeFile.Contains("Invalid")) { 
    MessageBox.Show("Word 'Invalid' Found"); 
} else {
. . .
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution for me. It avoids having to dump the contents of the file into an array and gets me my answer right away.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by doing `arrText.Contains("Invalid")`, you're searching each element of the `array` for "Invalid", so unless you have a single line in your text file with that text, it won't be found.

You need to search each *line* as you're building the array, and set your flag there.

```
var isFound = false;
var searchPhrase = "Invalid";

while (sLine != null)
{
    sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
    if (sLine != null)
    {
        arrText.Add(sLine);
        if (sLine.Contains(searchPhrase)) isFound = true;
    }
}

if (isFound)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Word Invalid Found");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nada");
}
```

Comment: Ok, so will that work if the line contains more than the word "Invalid" or do I need to do something else?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on whether you care whether it contains more than one invalid.  It will work either way.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
private void test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("C:\\testing\\mslogon.log");
    string sLine = "";
    ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
    MessageBox.Show("File Read");

    while (sLine != null)
    {
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
        if (sLine != null)
        {
            arrText.Add(sLine);
        }
    }
    foreach(string x in arrText)
    {
      if (x.Contains("Word Invalid Found"))
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing Found");
      }
      else
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Nada");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not very big, consider reading all text at once using [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function.

Also, by default, search is done in a case sensitive manner, so you will miss "word invalid found".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing way too much work. If all you want to know is whether the file contains any line with the word "Invalid" in it, you don't have to read the whole file at once. And you can stop at the first line you find. Consider this:

```
bool found = false;
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\testing\mslogon.log");
foreach (var sLine in lines)
{
    if (sLine.IndexOf("Invalid") != -1)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found it!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not found.");
}
```

And, you can replace that `foreach` with a LINQ expression:

```
bool found = lines.Where(sLine => sLine.IndexOf("Invalid") != -1).Any();
```

The key here is that `File.ReadLines` creates an enumerator that lets you read the file one line at a time, rather than loading the entire file into memory. In the loop, the `break` terminates the loop early if a line is found. In the `LINQ` expression, the `Any` method does essentially the same thing. The point being that if "Invalid" is found on the first line, there's no need to read through the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search in every item of array, in your actual code, only a string with the exact content "Invalid" will work.

Using LINQ, you can do this:

```
    if (arrText
        .ToArray()
        .Where(p => ((string)p).Contains("Invalid")).Any())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Word Invalid Found");
    }
```